# How pivot longer and match the variable name with a secondary table?

Tags: r, dataframe, match, recode

I'm struggling with the logic in order to cross these 2 tables:

My dataframes are:

`df6` includes an id and a numeric value per column. `v1` `v2` and `v3` will always have one and only one non-zero value, which indicates the `yummyness` value of that variable.

```
id v1 v2 v3
1  0  0  3
2  2  0  0
3  0  1  0
```

`df_yummy` contains the name equivalence for `v1` `v2` and `v3` as well as a "yummyness" value.

```
VarId   VarName  Yummyness
v1      Apple    2
v2      Lemon    1
v3      Peach    3
```

My desired outcome should have

```
id  Fruit  Yummyness
1   Peach  3
2   Apple  2
3   Lemon  1
```

EDIT: Typo correction

Comment: It's not at all apparent to me how these actually would cross together. For id = 1, the V3 variable in filled in, but you have id = 1 being Apple in your outcome. ???

Comment: Im sorry. I had a typo in my desired outcome. I corrected it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is one solution to your problem within the tidyverse (it is critical to assure that v1, v2 and v3 only show one value per line diferent than zero else you will get duplication or missing data):

```
#dummy data
df1 <- data.table::fread("id v1 v2 v3
1  0  0  3
2  2  0  0
3  0  1  0")

df2 <- data.table::fread("VarId   VarName  Yummyness
v1      Apple    2
v2      Lemon    1
v3      Peach    3")

library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(-id, names_to = "VarId", values_to = "vals") %>%
    dplyr::filter(vals != 0) %>%
    dplyr::right_join(df2, by = "VarId") %>%
    dplyr::select(id, Fruit = VarName,  Yummyness)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id Fruit Yummyness
  <int> <chr>     <int>
1     1 Peach         3
2     2 Apple         2
3     3 Lemon         1
```

Comment: thanks. why a right join and not a left one?

Comment: @AndresMora the right join is essentially a left join, when you invert the order of tables/data.frames... I just used it to stay within the same pipe, as it started with df1

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple solution that uses base R.

```
# Dummy data
df6 <- data.frame(
    id = c(1, 2, 3),
    v1 = c(0, 2, 0),
    v2 = c(0, 0, 1),
    v3 = c(3, 0, 0)
)

df_yummy <- data.frame(
    VarId = c("v1", "v2", "v3"),
    VarName = c("Apple", "Lemon", "Peach"),
    Yummyness = c(2, 1, 3)
)

df6$VarId <- names(df6[-1])[apply(X = df6[-1] > 0, MARGIN = 1, FUN = which)]
df_result <- merge(df6, df_yummy)[, c("id", "VarName", "Yummyness")]
names(df_result) <- c("id", "Fruit", "Yummyness")

> df_result[order(df_result$id), ]
  id Fruit Yummyness
3  1 Peach         3
1  2 Apple         2
2  3 Lemon         1
```

The crux of this solution is found in `apply(X = df6[-1] > 0, MARGIN = 1, FUN = which)`. What this does is take your `df6` and removes the first column (the `[-1]`) portion and then finds which records are greater than zero. We then use the `apply` function to apply the `which` function over the rows (the MARGIN = 1) portion. This means that for every row, we are returning the index which is non-zero. We pass this to `names()` to get the right name for each, and then the rest is just some joins.

Here's a slightly more compact version that uses the `data.table` package.

```
library(data.table)
# Dummy data
df6 <- data.table(
    id = c(1, 2, 3),
    v1 = c(0, 2, 0),
    v2 = c(0, 0, 1),
    v3 = c(3, 0, 0)
)

df_yummy <- data.table(
    VarId = c("v1", "v2", "v3"),
    VarName = c("Apple", "Lemon", "Peach"),
    Yummyness = c(2, 1, 3)
)

df6[, VarId := names(df6)[-1][which(.SD > 0)], by = id]
df_result <- merge(df6, df_yummy)[order(id), list(id, Fruit = VarName, Yummyness)]
```

This operates on much the same principle; we use the `which` function on the `data.table` specific `.SD`, by `id`, and then use this to pick the right name. This ends up slightly more compact because of the DT syntax but isn't fundamentally all that different.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```r
library(dplyr)

df6 %>% 
  mutate(Yummyness = rowSums(across(v1:v3)), .keep = "unused") %>% 
  left_join(df_yummy, by = "Yummyness") %>% 
  select(id, Fruit = VarName, Yummyness)
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id Fruit Yummyness
  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
1     1 Peach         3
2     2 Apple         2
3     3 Lemon         1
```

### Data

```r
df6 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3), v1 = c(0, 2, 0), v2 = c(0, 0, 
1), v3 = c(3, 0, 0)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), v1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), v2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), v3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))

df_yummy <- structure(list(VarId = c("v1", "v2", "v3"), VarName = c("Apple", 
"Lemon", "Peach"), Yummyness = c(2, 1, 3)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(VarId = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), VarName = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Yummyness = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option

```
setorder(
  melt(setDT(df6), id.var = "id")[
    value != 0
  ][setDT(df_yummy),
    on = ("variable == VarId")
  ],
  by = "id"
)[, .(id, VarName, Yummyness)]
```

gives

```
   id VarName Yummyness
1:  1   Peach         3
2:  2   Apple         2
3:  3   Lemon         1
```